# How to stop xaringan's keyboard shortcuts while searching in a DT::datatable()?

Tags: r, datatables, remarkjs, xaringan

xaringan's keyboard shortcuts interfere with DT::datatable() search functionality. It can even be seen in [xaringan's example presentation](https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/#22) (for instance, attempt to search for "m").

How can I stop this from happening? It is practically impossible to search for anything in a DT::datatable(). Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you using xaringan?

Comment: I'm building a presentation with R and RMarkdown. Is there a better way? Apart from this problem, xaringan is working amazingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the keyboard shortcut by using `frameWidget` in `widgetframe` R package. Below is a working example.

````
```{r}
library(widgetframe)
library(DT)
dt <-  datatable(iris)
frameWidget(dt)
```
````

Comment: this is a nice workaround, but then all the CSS gets lost. It would be nice if there was an actual way to disable xaringan's keyboard shortcuts

Comment: Yes, I agree that it would be nice to have an easier way to disable keyboard shortcuts for some specified slides. This is a limitation more on `remark.js` rather than `xaringan` though. Perhaps upvote/comment [here](https://github.com/gnab/remark/issues/544) to get some attention from the developers there?