# Currently there is a way to disable some keyboard shortcuts in xaringan slides?

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt, xaringan

I have a DT table with some normality test results, the idea is that the reader can search for the result he/she is interested in using the keyboard.

The problem is that when typing some words the Xaringan keyboard shortcuts start to interfere with the search which is obviously annoying.

[image]

I tried what people answered in this question and it didn't work.

[How to stop xaringan's keyboard shortcuts while searching in a DT::datatable()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819724/how-to-stop-xaringans-keyboard-shortcuts-while-searching-in-a-dtdatatable)

```
library(reticulate)
library(DT)
library(widgetframe)
library(htmlwidgets)
df = py$data
dt <-  datatable(df)
frameWidget(dt)
```

result:

[image]

If anyone knows of a way to solve this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: So what exactly did you try? It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.